# Can't get FindId to work (GO + MGO)

Tags: go, mgo

Not sure what's going on here... but I'm having a heck of a time trying to get a simple operation done. I'm new to GO (trying to switch from Node) so it's probably a Type thing...

```
User struct {
        ID_ bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"`
        UTC time.Time     `bson:"utc,omitempty" json:"utc,omitempty"`
        USR string        `bson:"usr,omitempty" json:"usr,omitempty"`
        PWD string        `bson:"pwd,omitempty" json:"pwd,omitempty"`
    }
func save(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  m := s.Copy()
  defer m.Close()
  user := m.DB("0").C("user")
  var a User
  json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&a)
  err := user.FindId(a.ID_)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

This returns the following error

```
http: panic serving [::1]:53092: &{{0 0} 0xc208062600 {{0.user [{_id TE?????}] 0 0 ?
reflect.Value? 0 <nil> {?reflect.Value? ?reflect.Value? ?reflect.Value? false false [] 0}     
false []} 0.25 0}}
```

When I run:

```
a.ID_.Valid()
```

I get "true".

PS. I can get this to work:

```
func user(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  m := s.Copy()
  defer m.Close()
  user := m.DB("0").C("user")
  a := &User{ID_:bson.NewObjectId(), UTC:time.Now()}
  b, _ := json.Marshal(a)
  user.Insert(a)
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I am. I pasted the error above. It comes from this line user.FindId(a.ID_). I'm struggling because a.ID_ is a valid ObjectId.

Comment: I'm such a noob at this... you're right. Thanks. Feel free to put that in the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FindId](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.FindId) method returns a [Query](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query), not an error. Call the Query [One](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.One) method to get the document.

Answer (score 3):

As per the docs http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.FindId

`FindId` returns a `Query` struct which you can then call any of its functions. `FindId` does not return an error.

Try

```
var userDoc interface{}
if err := user.FindId(a.ID_).One(&userDoc); err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

You can change `interface{}` with whatever struct you are using for users.